# What does the multiply operator do relational algebra?

Tags: relational-algebra

I'm new to relational algebra. I found the `*` operator in the following expression

[image]

What's the different this and one using join

[image]

Comment: What symbol means what operator & what each operator does & what a "relation" is--what "relational algebra means--depends on the textbook & section. (Algebras with dots usually have relations with headings that are lists that can have duplicate attribute names & have \* or × as product & ⋈ with arguments as equijoin or θ-join. And often are really query languages & not actually algebras.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `*` should more correctly be written `×` as it represents a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). This operation returns the set of all tuples that are the concatenation of tuples from each operand. A join filters the Cartesian product down to only those tuples with matching values on specified attributes. If the join is a natural join, as in your example, the attributes matched on are those with identical names.

For example, given the following two relations `R` and `S` as shown:

```
R ( a, b, c )      S ( b, c, d )
  ( 1, 2, 3 )        ( 2, 7, 9 )
  ( 2, 4, 6 )        ( 5, 3, 4 )
  ( 3, 6, 9 )        ( 2, 3, 6 )
```

The Cartesian product `R × S` is:

```
  ( R.a, R.b, R.c, S.b, S.c, S.d )
  ( 1,   2,   3,   2,   7,   9   )
  ( 1,   2,   3,   5,   3,   4   )
  ( 1,   2,   3,   2,   3,   6   )
  ( 2,   4,   6,   2,   7,   9   )
  ( 2,   4,   6,   5,   3,   4   )
  ( 2,   4,   6,   2,   3,   6   )
  ( 3,   6,   9,   2,   7,   9   )
  ( 3,   6,   9,   5,   3,   4   )
  ( 3,   6,   9,   2,   3,   6   )
```

The natural join `R ⨝ S` is the product filtered to only tuples where the `b` and `c` values match:

```
  ( a, b, c, d )
  ( 1, 2, 3, 6 )
```

The join `R ⨝b S` is the product filtered to only tuples where the `b` values match:

```
  ( R.a, b,   R.c, S.c, S.d )
  ( 1,   2,   3,   7,   9   )
  ( 1,   2,   3,   3,   6   )
```

Comment: The book "Fundamentals of Database Systems" - 6th edition uses the multiplication sign * as an alternative notation for natural join on page 159 (6th edition, ISBN 0136086209).

Answer (score 1):

In few books natural join is denoted by an astric(*).