# Why can't I compare 2 tables with Different number of Tuples in Relational?

Tags: relational-database, relational-algebra, relational

A Question came up in class and I am not sure I am understanding the answer. In the program relational https://ltworf.github.io/relational/ , when using the  ∩  operator, you MUST have tables with the same number of Tuples ( My teacher said like comparing apples to apples, not apples to oranges ). However, if I run a query on just 1 column in 2 Tables ( like city in a user database, and city in a storeLocation DB ), why is it required that the tables have the same number of Tuples?

If I want to compare City in 2 tables, why does each table need to have the same tuples. Why can't I just query on city without having to worry about the number of tuples in the table.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Also, links die. Insert images/links using edit functions. Make your post self-contained.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding natural join in Relational algebra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52174474/3404097)

Comment: ∩ requires the same attributes, not the same number of tuples. Do you have a typo or a misunderstanding? There are many RAs (relational algebras). They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Give definitions of "relation" &  ∩ & ⋈. Use the definitions to try to answer this yourself--show research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Also: What does "query on city" mean? Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. PS ∩ is a special case of ⋈. We use ∩ instead of ⋈ *to show that we expect the attributes to be the same*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you to be able to use the normal set operators (`- ∪ ∩`) on relations, they need to be the same "kind" of relation. That is, they need to have the same columns.

To achieve that, you need to use projection and rename.

So if you have a relation `A` with fields `id, name` and you want to do a union with a relation `B` which has `id, first_name, last_name` you need to do: `A ∪ πid, name (ρ first_name ➡name (B))`

Answer (score 1):

[wikipedia on Codd's intersection operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Set_operators) -- that is, your `∩`

> For set union and set difference, the two relations involved must be
>   *union-compatible* — that is, the two relations must have the same set of attributes. Because set intersection is defined in terms of set
>   union and set difference, the two relations involved in set
>   intersection must also be union-compatible.

Nothing about the numbers of tuples in the arguments.

BTW that 'relational' you link to seems very poor. On the page "Explaination [sic] of all the operators and their syntax ", there is neither an explanation of the semantics nor the syntax of operators. I would expect it to explain about requiring the attributes to be the same. It only has one example using `∩`, "These are some valid queries." and that is very complex and invalid in many ways:

```
ρ id➡i,name➡n(A) - π a,b(π a,b(A)) ∩ σage > 25 or rank = weight(A)
```

- `σage > 25 or rank = weight(A)` is wrong: there should be double `==` for the comparison, as in the first example.
- There doesn't seem to be a precedence system between the binary operators, so does the `-` bind tighter than the `∩`?
- Either way, the arguments to `-`and to `∩` are not union-compatible: the projection `π a,b(A)` has only attributes `a,b` whereas the selection `σ` has all attributes of `A` (including `age, rank`) and the projection `ρ` has all attributes other than those renamed to `i, n`.

No wonder you're confused. Who told you to use the program relational? I would throw it away.

Comment: The language is formally defined here https://ltworf.github.io/relational/grammar.html

Operations are not explained, in the same way that in a javascript manual they won't explain what a multiplication is, but only how to do that in javascript.

Precedence is left to right, unary operators have more precedence.

Comment: @LtWorf I looked at that page. That's syntax only, no explanation. The page is one of the reasons I said "[no] explanation". If you understand the need for projection/rename, from your answer, you'll see the example I discuss is out-and-out wrong. OK perhaps I shouldn't say "[no] explanation" but "a bad and misleading explanation".

Comment: I'm the author. Yes the examples should probably be the same as the video tutorial, in which some queries are executed. I still maintain that one should just go to wikipedia to know what the operations do. In general people who want to run relational algebra are studying it and have other material to learn the operations.

Comment: @LtWorf "one should just go to wikipedia to know what the operations do". There are many variants of Relational Algebra. Many do not support Outer Joins, because it introduces Nulls. So your site definitely needs to give a reference to which operators you're using, and their semantics. Re `Null` you don't appear to have a way for testing for it (such as SQL `IS [NOT] NULL`). So I suspect the query language is not expressively complete.

Comment: the select expressions are just normal python, you can write whatever you want there.